# parsedjson string - name return w/out special characters

Tags: json, parsing, special-characters, facebook-php-sdk

I want to fetch the name of users clicking on login. I've done this successfully.. The only problem is names with special characters. FOr instance, my name: 
- Håvar Bjørnseth 
with the special characters; å and ø, will return: HÃ¥var BjÃ¸rnseth

Is there any way to fix this so that the correct letters will return?

The code I used to retrieve the name:

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $user_id);
        $parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
        echo $parsedJson->name;
```

If any of you know how to call the name using Javascript SDK, I would love to hear about it! Thank you :)

Comment: Can you make the same call with Javascript SDK and let us know if it returns the correct characters?

Comment: I would :P but to be honest I don't know how! I'm not a very skilled programmer :-). Thanks for replying though!

Comment: Give it a try, you'd be surprised as to what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you can try to access the link

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=704597208

You can observe that facebook is returning the correct characters. I am thinking your problem is with the character encoding which you are using. Probably you can try converting the name you get to your desired encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) 
Now I know it can be done using PHP.
No idea how though :p

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use the Facebook PHP SDK.  It should automatically handle the encoding issues.  See:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/